# MySQL all parent-child relationships

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I have a table named `table`. It has a field named `id` with type `INT(11)` that stands for an identifier of the row, it has other fields but I don't think they are relevant for this problem.

I have another table named `table_children`. It has a field named `parent` with type `INT(11)` that refers to `table.id` as a foreign key. It has another field named `child`  with type `INT(11)` that also refers to `table.id` as a foreign key. This table describes `table` row to `table` row parent-child relationships.

Here is a probable setting.

```
table   table_children
id      parent child
0       0      1
1       1      2
2       1      3
3       3      4
4
```

How can I get the `id`'s of all the descendents of `0` in a minimum number of requests? The answer here would be `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MySQL, the easiest way I do this is to store *all* paths in the tree, creating a [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).

```
table_children
parent child
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
0      1
0      2
0      3
0      4
1      2
1      3
1      4
3      4
```

Now you can query it thus:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table_children c
JOIN table t ON c.child = t.id
WHERE c.parent = 0;
```

See also:

- [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)
- [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)
- [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/)

Comment: I will go with this. It seems efficient to me since this table is pre-processed and only one query is performed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL was not designed to work with recursive queries, I wrote up Stored Procedures to handle this. Please see my DBA StackExchange post : [**Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161/877)

I wrote up the following functions

- `GetParentIDByID`
- `GetAncestry`
- `GetFamilyTree`

Answer (score 0):

With the way your data is currently setup, there is efficient way to get all descendents.  You would query something like this:

```
SELECT child FROM table_children WHERE parent in (x, y, z);
```

where x,y, and z are all the chidren retrieved in the previous iteration.  Repeat the query until you got no more rows.  This will take as many queries as  the depth of your tree.

However, if you are open to changing the way you store your tree in the DB, there is another alternative called MPTT (Modified Pre-order Tree Traversal) that will allow you to fetch an entire subtree with a single query, although updates are trickier.  You need to figure out whether the extra complexity for inserts a good tradeoff for your application for the benifit of efficient retrievals.

There is an excellent article explaining MPTT [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/).